# How to call db repository public class method from WCF service in .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am newbie in WCF,  i have my entities and entity dal repository classes for performing database operations. 
What i want is to place all my db code like Add, Edit, Delete etc in Service. So i can call from web forms from asp.net 4.0.

Suppose there is a method of Add, that method definition is in my db repository class, what i need is to use that class in my wcf service, but i do not know the exact syntax how to do that.
Following is the way i have adopted for project structure and wcf code. please forgive if i asked anything wrong,
[image]

Comment: What is your actual question, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your exact question is.
Your Registration class looks weird.

You should define your interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataAccess
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Add(Member m);

    // Other methods for your service
}
```

You implement the service in your class as you would do with other interfaces:

```
public class Registration : IRegistration
{
    public bool Add(Member m)
    {
        try 
        {
            new MemberRepository().Add(m);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception) { return false; }
    }

    // Other IRegistration implementations
}
```

Also your way of handling the exception is potentially hiding bugs in your code. See MSDN blog on [Vexing Exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please let me know is this necessary in WCF services to implement the interface? And would i be able to call these wcf services from my android or iphone app?

Comment: I think this [MSDN article on basic WCF programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms731067(v=vs.90).aspx) should help you to answer your questions on how to implement services correctly.